# strange padding with max-height

Tags: html, css

I have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/8rYVf/) : as you can see nothing of strange.

But, if I try to remove `max-height:150px;` from `main_inside` I see a small background red in the bottom of the image.

Why? It should be sized regard the `max-height` of the image class `myImage`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images put spaces below them in some browsers.
The following will provide an easy fix.

```
.myImage{max-width:200px; border:0px; padding: 0px; display: block;}
```

Comment: Oh...and I see that this trick works only with padding+display block (without block no). It's Strange...isnt?